# 'Python - Bokeh' How to use .css file with parameter "css_classes" in widget in bokeh?

Tags: python, css, bokeh

Currently I want to use css file in bokeh in python, so I google for an example to do so. Here is the example I get now.

my_app/main.py

```
from bokeh.layouts import layout
from bokeh.plotting import curdoc, column
from bokeh.models import Button

button = Button(label="Test Button", css_classes=['custom_button_bokeh'])
layout = layout(button)
curdoc().add_root(layout)
```

my_app/templates/index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      {{ bokeh_css }}
      {{ bokeh_js }}
      <style type="text/css">{% include 'styles.css' %}</style>
    </head>
    <body>
      {{ plot_div|indent(8) }}
      {{ plot_script|indent(8) }}
    </body>
</html>
```

my_app/templates/styles.css

```
.custom_button_bokeh .bk.bk-btn.bk-btn-default button{
    color: black;
    font-size: 50pt;
    background-color: #05b7ff;
    border-color: #05b7ff;
}
```

I try to use bokeh server to show to plot with `bokeh serve --show my_app` but the style of the button still not change. The bokeh version I'm using is 3.1.0, and Python is 3.9.

Thank you all in advance!

I'll be very happy to hear any possible solution from you guys, thanks!!!